# How Do You Navigate Backwards To the Previous Page instead of the Root Page

Tags: maui

In my app I have multiple pages, but when I try and navigate backwards, instead of going to the previous page it always goes to the root page (MainPage).  On Android, it's bad because you lose all context.  On iOS it's worse, because it causes an exception in the Program class here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
        // you can specify it here.
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, typeof(AppDelegate));
    }
```

The exception is System.NullReferenceException.  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'm navigating like this - I'm starting out on my MainPage, and I navigate to the next page like this:

```
FriendsPage fp = new FriendsPage();
await Navigation.PushAsync(fp, true);
```

On that page, I'm going to the next page like this:

```
            FriendRatingsPage frp = new FriendRatingsPage() { SearchResults = results, FriendRatingListType = FriendRatingsPage.RatingListType.FriendsItemRatings };

#if ANDROID
            await Navigation.PushAsync(frp, true);
#else
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(frp, true);
#endif
```

Modal pages are broken it seems for Android right now, which is why the two different approaches.

Once I'm on the third page, I want to go back to the previous page.  So I follow the directions explained here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation.  It says "Backwards navigation can be performed by specifying ".." as the argument to the GoToAsync method".  So I have a click handler that does so like this:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
```

And that's where things go sideways as I described above - going back to the MainPage instead of the previous page, which was the FriendsPage.  I've gone in circles on this but clearly am missing something.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: you are mixing two different kinds of navigation.  If you navigate forward using `PushAsync()`, then you navigate back using `PopAsync()`.  Same with `PushModalAsync` and `PopModalAsync`.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I had tried that too (sorry I forgot to mention that) and Pop also takes me back to the MainPage instead of the previous page.

Comment: are you using shell navigation elsewhere in the app?  It still sounds like you are mixing the two different navigation mechanisms

Comment: While this flow did not use shell navigation, I ended up changing all of the navigation in my app to use Shell and now I no longer have this problem.